# How can i post a json data to rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, curl

I want to send the user information for sign up and the following is the request

curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST `http://localhost:3000/users.json` -d "{"user" : {"Email":sample@example.com, "password":qwerty, "password_confirmation":qwerty}}"

but i receive an error as

MultiJson::DecodeError (795: unexpected token at '{user : {Email:sample@example.com, password:qwerty, password_confirmation:qwerty}}')

I do not know what wrong i am doing? Please help me.

Comment: Your strings are not in quotes, so it's just a syntax issue. You can run your data through http://jsonlint.com/ to make sure it's OK.

Comment: I have tried as you have told but the result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one,

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -X POST http://localhost:3000/users.json -d "{\"user\":{\"email\":\"sample@example.com\", \"password\":\"qwerty\",\"password_confirmation\":\"qwerty\"}}"
```

Problem was with the parameters parsing, need to be within quotes.

Comment: sorry now the error has changed to WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

TypeError (can't convert StringIO into String):

Comment: yes, it works now. But i have tried devise example from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise_example where i do not have to put the escape sequences there. so how can i do that kind?

Comment: What you trying to achieve with this? Are you creating the remote authentication with devise? if yes then you have to overwrite the devise's session controller to respond to json request.

Comment: Actually i am now working with simple restful authentication but i have tried the devise example in the mean time and i tried posting the values without escape sequence and it worked so good. So i wanted to send json without escape sequence here also.

Comment: here the escape sequence is only concern with curl, nothing to do with devise.

Comment: As i have said, i have not used the escape sequence in the curl for devise example but it worked and i got the resulting json. so how that alone is working?

Comment: curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:3000/login.json -d "{"user" : {"username":xxxxxxxx, "password":yyyyyyyyy}}"   and it is working correct.

Comment: if it is working correctly then what is the problem? I tried that one at my end but no luck.

Comment: Sorry, I have cloned that example from github and tried and it is working for that example only but when i do on my own it is not working. It works only in the way you have told. I wanted all other apps also to work like the example.

Comment: In that case I can only suggest you to compare these to apps with utility like meld and also the web logs...